# jquery dynamic creation of element but click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any jQuery help would be appreciated.  I have two objects (identical) created with jquery. One loads when document opens (append to body tag) and the other appends to body tag as well within a button click event.  When I click on the first it fires an alert message but second one doesn't ( would like it to fire as well).  I have included the JSFiddle link with my code.

My Code:

```
<label for="" id="Label01" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:15px;width:186px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:8;">Button Created</label>

<label for="" id="Label02" style="position:absolute;left:190px;top:15px;width:186px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:8;">Without Button</label> 

<label for="" id="Label03" style="position:absolute;left:30px;top:115px;width:150px;height:18px;line-height:18px;z-index:1;">Click on a image</label>

<input type="submit" id="Button1" value="Create Image" style="position:absolute;left:495px;top:100px;width:106px;height:35px;z-index:0;">

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>    
<script>

var $i1;
var $circle;
var dot = "dot1";
var dot_btn = "dot2";

// next (3) lines will create circle image and append to body WITHOUT button 
 click event
 $i1 =$('<i/>').attr({ class: "far fa-dot-circle fa-2x" });
 $circle = $('<div/>').attr({ id: dot 
 }).css({"position":"absolute","left":"200px","top":"40px"}).append($i1);
 $("body").append($circle);


// button click to create another circle image
$("#Button1").click(function() {             // click event - triggers a 

alert("btn clicked");
var btnCircle;

$i1 =$('<i/>').attr({ class: "far fa-dot-circle fa-2x" });
btnCircle = $('<div>').attr({ id: dot_btn 
}).css({"position":"absolute","left":"10px","top":"40px"}).append($i1);

$('#dot2').bind('click', function() { });
$("body").append(btnCircle);

});      


// NOTE only "dot1" works (without creation using the button click jquery 
  code)
$("#dot1").on("click",function() {
   alert("dot1 clicked");
});


$("#dot2").on("click",function() {
   alert("dot2 clicked");
});

</script>
```

Here is jsfiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/jgwilly54/q13aLko8/1/

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code from

```
$("#dot2").on("click",function() {
   alert("dot2 clicked");
});
```

To

```
$(document).on("click", "#dot2" ,function() {
   alert("dot2 clicked");
});
```

Ref: [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Probably a cleaner solution than mine!

Comment: Thank you!  Works great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off cloning your object - this replicates the entire thing, including any events and/or data you want to bring along.

https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Just did this on your fiddle, it works.

```
$("#Button1").click(function() {      
  $newObject = $( $firstObject ).clone().css( 'left', '10px' ).appendTo( 'body' );
  $( $newObject ).click( function() {
  alert( 'hey there!' );
  });
});
```